# Simple regex expression to find capital letters is returning small letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm expecting this simple Regex expresison to return `null` since there are no capital letters in

```js
var a = "hiho";
var res = a.match(/[A-Z]/gi);

alert(res)
```

the string.

Yet, it is returning an array of each small letter.

Why?

Comment: You know regex flags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the `ignoreCase` (`i`) flag, which makes your regex *case-insensitive*. Remove it and your regex should work as intended.

```
var res = a.match(/[A-Z]/g);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the expression

```
/[A-Z]/gi
```

The "i" means "case insensitive", which is why both lower and upper case are matching.